# How to get form data with $_POST from same page when it is submitted by $.ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have *index.php* page and within that page, there is a form. Within a form I have a text field and I want to retrieve that value using $`_POST` within that *index.php* page.

The problem is I'm using JQUERY AJAX within my *index.php*. I also have `$.ajax` function. `$.ajax` function is to pass the data to another PHP page. If I return false in `$.ajax` function, the form will not submit.

So I cannot retrieve that value using `$_POST`. If I don't return false in `$.ajax` function, I can retrieve form value using `$_POST` within that *index.php*. But, $.ajax function will not work. How can I make it work both `$.ajax` function and `$_POST` to get value from that text field within that index.php.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should be fairly basic. You prevent the default submit action, not the the ajax call, and send a POST request with ajax to a PHP script on the server which you can retrieve with $_POST.

Comment: I need to use $_POST within that index.php page not from other page because of my need. I know I can retrieve form value using $_POST from other page. But, my problem is I just want to retrieve form value using $_POST and $.ajax function is also used in that page.

Comment: Then you're not understanding how it works, you can't really use $_POST within a page on the clientside, as it's a server based language, and you have to run a script on the server when doing ajax calls, otherwise there is no need for ajax, and you can just submit the form and reload the page, that would probably work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).on("submit","form", function() {
       $.post('index.php', $("form").serialize(),function(d) {

       });
       return false;
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use session variables. When you get the POST, set SESSION as the values you want to temporarily store. Then, after you use them, you can empty the session.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `$("#form").submit()`, after ajax is sent succesfully

```
$.ajax({ 
url: 'getPost.php', 
type: 'POST', 
data: value,
success: function(data){
 $('#container').html(data); 
 $('#myForm').submit();
}
});
```

where `value = {name: "noname"} // javascript object(json)`

Comment: Thanks Alexandru. I'll try to do it :)

Comment: Be sure to use e.preventDefault() to prevent the form from submiting.

Comment: Is it the right way to do that? $.ajax({
    url: 'getPost.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {value:value }
    }).done(function(data) {
     $('#container').html(data);
     $('#myForm').submit();
     return false;
     
    });

Comment: I just checked the jQuery documentation, i see they changed the ajax thingy a bit(i'm not sure if my code stil works, depending on what jquery version you're using), i suppose a correction to your code would be `{value: "value"}` and remove the `return false`

Comment: Now I'm trying again with the way you showed on top. The page refreshes and and show me some data in my index.php. But the problem is ajax part is not working. I'm using Jquery 1.9.0. The way I use is here.                                                        $.ajax({ 
url: 'process_tweets.php', 
type: 'POST', 
data: {value: value, location: location, radius: radius, radiusValue: radiusValue },
success: function(data){
 $('#container').html(data); 
 $('#myForm').submit();
 return false;
}
});

Comment: Open firebug console and check if you have any errors. i suppose location, radius, radiusValue are all variables, if not, put them in quotes. And you must have something like `$("#form").submit(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /* rest of the ajax and code/* });`

Comment: I have already debugged with developer console. There is no error at all.

Comment: check my comment edit. If that doesn't solve it, give me url to your javascript, and i'll look throught it.

Comment: I'm using Jquery 1.9. I also tried like you said above. It still didn't solve my problem. My code is here:

Comment: $("#myForm").submit(function(e) { 
     var value = $('input#value').val();
      var location = $('input#searchTextField').val();
  var radius = $('input#radius').val();
  var radiusValue = $('select#radiusValue').val();
     e.preventDefault(); 
  
     $.ajax({
    url: 'process_tweets.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { value: value, location: location, radius: radius, radiusValue: radiusValue }
    }).done(function(data) {
     $('#container').html(data);   
     alert("Success");
    });
    });

Comment: I had one error sorry. Please check this link, i made some test page http://yodait.9smi.com/test.html The thing is you can't have submit, and then submit again, it will make an eternal loop. So instead, put an Id on the submit button and call function like `$("#button").click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); // });` check the link for further information

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try to do that and check your link again :)

Comment: I changed my code according to your link. Still $.ajax() doesn't work. But can get data with $_POST within same page. The problem still exists. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with different approaches like

1: You can have a hidden field and form then populate that field with the same value of text field while sending ajax call and then submit that form after completion of ajax call

2: You can also preserve the value of text field in a java script variable. Then make a temporary form using javascript and submit that variable with that form.